# Using a comma before “which”, and whether to use “which” or “that”

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, commas

I have two sentences in my personal statement which I am not sure about.

> Additionally, it will expose me to multiple cultures **which** will enhance my patient interaction and networking skills, and allow me to become an effective leader.
>
> Also, I would like to establish a research center **that** will conduct research on different aspects of clinical pharmacy **which** will improve the healthcare system in my country and make Egypt a leader in healthcare services.

I am not sure if I am using “which” and “that” right or not and whether to put comma before which or just leave it like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which) PLUS [comma before which](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259368/comma-before-which) (and two questions).