# My cards associated with the bank account

Tags: verbs, tenses, commas, verb-agreement, modal-verbs

1. My cards associated with this bank account include a debit card, a credit card, etc.
2. My cards which are associated with this bank account include a debit card, a credit card, etc.
3. My cards which are associated with this bank account include a debit card, a credit card, etc.

Can anybody tell me the difference between these sentences? Do we need a comma after 'which' in the second sentence. How do we know whether the inflected form of the verb 'Be', that is 'are', in the 2nd and 3rd questions is the main verb 'Be' or the auxiliary verb 'Be'?

Comment: "With this bank" and "with this bank account" don't mean the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it appropriate to put a comma before "which"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54532/is-it-appropriate-to-put-a-comma-before-which)

Comment: (2) and (3) need a comma before 'which' and one after 'account'  if they are using non-defining and need zero punctuation there if they are using defining relative clauses. The 'reduced relative clause' sentence (according to some) similarly has commas after 'cards' and after 'account', or zero punctuation, to indicate whether the postmodifier is intended to be non-defining or defining.